# HTML scroll image having height as auto?

Tags: css, html

Is there an alternate way to scroll an image with the height set as auto at all? Because I have an image that does not fully fit into the div container and
I don't want to force px in the height attribute:

```
    <div style="height: auto; width: 150px; overflow: scroll;">
        <img> .....bla bla bla
    </div>
```

Comment: what means <!-- the image here -->? is it with `<img />` tag or do you add the image as `background-image` to the `<div>`?

Comment: height: autopx; is not valid CSS. It should be height: auto;

Comment: my bad, it's auto, will correct it

Comment: Not sure I understand the question really, what prevents you from just scaling the image to fit both height and width? How will this be used?

Answer (score 2):

Well you don't have to set the height of the div.

I made you an example with scrolling only the width: http://jsfiddle.net/ah3b20zs/13/

**HTML:**

```
<div style="height: auto; width: 150px; overflow-x: scroll;">
    <img src="yourimg" alt="caption" />
</div>
```

P.S.: I used exact witdh within the `<img>` because the source image was too big.

If you want to scroll height as well I don't think it's possible without saying from where it should start scrolling(setting `height` or `max-height` of the div).

So the question for you is: **When do you want it to start scrolling?**

Comment: that is true, but what if I needed the height? There must be a way. alternatively, I have to use media queries.

Comment: Was that a homework?.. when you say that you have to use something.. anyway if you want the height to be scrollable too, then you need to give the element some height from where it should start scrolling.. for example you could get the browser window height and make that the picture height or someting like that.. I'm still not sure what exact output you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

use this your height will be auto

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 150px; overflow: scroll;">
```

also you can add max-height to the code like this max-height:200px;

Comment: the image does not get scrollable with percentage. Doesn't solve my problem unfortunately :( running the html file on chrome